# Lock an input to focus. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my input to be locked to focus. I tried this

```
onBlur={this.click()}
```

but it didn't work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

give it an `autoFocus` (camelCase because its react/jsx) attribute

```
<input type="text" autoFocus/>
```

if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The autoFocus attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an  element should automatically get focus when the page loads.

Try this

Comment: i  agree with you, since he already executed with ()

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target.focus` instead of `click`. You might also want to [invoke this at the end of the event loop][1], i.e. after a timeout of 0ms:

```
const onBlur = (e) => {
  window.setTimeout(() => e.target.focus(), 0);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <input type="text" onBlur={onBlur} />
  </div>
);
```

See proof-of-concept example:

[image: Edit flamboyant-euclid-ow5xf]

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a ref to the input and set it to focus when the onBlur event is fired

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
const inputRef = React.useRef();

const handleOnblur = () => {
  inputRef.current.focus();
};

return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input ref={inputRef} onBlur={handleOnblur} placeholder="text1" />
      <input  placeholder="text2" />
    </div>
  );
}
```